# MySQL, how to get the largest value of one column?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

`SELECT` column `FROM` table `WHERE` column is largest?

Comment: The largest possible value, or the largest value currently stored in the column?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is the `where` clause affecting more than one column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT MAX(column) FROM table;
```

`MAX` is an [aggregate function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx); see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html).